# How to erase the axis lines in matplotlib without erasing contents?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In the following figure, I want to erase the x and y axis lines in the top right plot, how do I do this without erasing the text?

[image: The plot in question]

I've tried with:

```
axes[m,k].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
axes[m,k].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

but it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the axes off by using

```
ax.axis("off")
```

---

An example using seaborn `PairGrid`:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue="species")

g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3, legend=False)

def text(x,y, color, label):
    i = ["setosa", "versicolor","virginica"].index(label)
    xm = x.mean(); ym = y.mean()
    tx = "xmean: {}\nymean: {}".format(xm,ym)
    plt.text(.3,0.1+i*0.25,tx, color=color, transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
    plt.gca().axis("off")

g.map_upper(text)
plt.show()
```

[image]